# How to make an ajax call without callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using $.ajax() to send the data to a controller action that saves the data to a database. And after the data is saved, I don't need any callback function to the $.ajax(). I just want to render another view. But since this $.ajax() requires to get something back, I receive a parser error.

Here is my ajax call:

```
$("#submit_btn").click(handleSubmit);
 function handleSubmit(e) {
        alert("Clicked!");
        e.preventDefault();
        var ans = [];
        for (var i = 0; i <= id_txt; i++) {
            ans.push($("#_addText" + i).val())
        }
        var options = {};
        options.url = "/Technique/Steps";
        options.type = "POST";
        options.data = JSON.stringify(
        {
            Id: $("#Id").val(),
            Poradi: $("#Poradi").val(),
            TechniqueId: $("#TechniqueId").val(),
            Answers: ans
        });
        options.contentType = "application/json";
        options.dataType = "json";
        options.error = function (jqXHR, status, err) { alert(status + "from AJAX"); };
        $.ajax(options);
    };
```

Is there any way to say this method, that I do not need anything back, so please dont expect

```
return JSON(someobject)
```

from a controller action.

Comment: My guess is you get a parser error because you tell jQuery that you're dealing with JSON, but your server doesn't return JSON.  Make the type of the request match the type of data the server returns and you won't get this error.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, and I don't want to return JSON to jQuery, I just want it to send the data to a controller and nothing more. So if I return View(someobject), what should I pass then? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: jQuery has this functionality built in.  You could do a generic (non-jQuery) Ajax call and then just ignore the return result.  What is the server returning?  All you have to do is set `options.dataType` to match the type of data the server is returning that and the error will go away.  `dataType: "text"` will probably work because jQuery won't try to process the data like it is with `dataType: "json"` that you have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
options.dataType = "json";
```

to:

```
options.dataType = "text";
```

Since the text format requires no processing by jQuery when the response arrives and you aren't looking for a return value anyway, there's little room for a parsing error with the `dataType` set to "`text"`.

Comment: One more question - Is it possible anyhow to tell jQuery not to expect any response?

Comment: @ShukhratRaimov - there is always some type of response that indicates whether the request succeeded or failed or was redirected or something else.  That's how an http request works.  There does not have to be any data associated with the response beyond the plain [http portion of the response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html).  But clearly your server is sending some data back.